# Make reusable component with depending on various services to use across multiple Angular applications

Tags: angular

We have three different applications that serves for different purposes, however the login component is the same along them, the style, positions etc. The only thing changes is that the logo and background image. So, we decided to make a reusable component to use in other applications.

So far it is sound easy, however, the `login.service.ts` depends on the other two services inside of the application such as authentication, jwt, etc. And these two application also depends on other two services in the application. So it is a chain of logic.

The services along the other applications are the same but under the different folder structure as well.

I'm new to Angular, and I read that we can use Angular Libraries and publish outside.

My question is, since the services are depending on the other ones, how the logic should be? I thought putting the services also as library but the part I don't get it how the input output logic should be.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you already using NX or Lerna?

Comment: I believe no, the only thing i know is that they use Artifactory to publish and the base is from JHipster.

Comment: Do you want to do something like this ?
https://medium.com/angular-unfold/how-to-build-reusable-library-in-angular-c172c3a85032

Comment: Instead of how to use Angular library, i would like to understand the logic of multiple services. The contain information inside the link is equal to the Angular doc tho